# Can I use the same pointer for 2 different structures?

Tags: c, list, structure

```
    typedef struct{
        int numero, curso, ano, regime;
    }dados_aluno;
    typedef struct{
        char disc[MAX_NOME];
        char nome[MAX_NOME];
    }dados_disc;

    typedef struct lnode *List;
    typedef struct lnode{
        dados_aluno info;
        List previous;
        List next;
    }aluno_node;
    typedef struct lnode{
        dados_disc info;
        List previous;
        List next;
    }disc_node;
```

redefinition of 'struct lnode' appears as an error.
Is there a way where is possible to use the same pointer (in this case '*List') for 2 different structures?

Comment: **Never ever** `typedef` a pointer to an object type!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to name the `struct` if `struct name` is not used anywhere.

So you could simply remove the second name, since it doesn't seem to be used:

```
typedef struct lnode *List;
typedef struct lnode{
    dados_aluno info;
    List previous;
    List next;
}aluno_node;
typedef struct{  // <== name removed
    dados_disc info;
    List previous;
    List next;
}disc_node;
```

Answering the question from the other answer:

```
typedef struct lnode *List;
```

does not declare `struct lnode`, it *uses* its definition (and, here, ahead of the declaration that is below). (and, no, `List` cannot point to two different types)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not committed to the data layout, you could reorganize your two structures:

```
struct list_node;
typedef struct list_node * List;

struct list_node {
    List prev;
    List next;
};

typedef struct {
    struct list_node list;
    dados_disc info;
} disc_node;
```

This would enable you to cast from List to pointer to disc_node (or any other node type), provided you have some way to know which is which.

Alternatively, you might consider using a `union` of the two types. Again, you will have to determine how to tell them apart:

```
typedef union lnode * List;

typedef ... disc_node;
typedef ... aluno_node;

typedef union lnode {
    disc_node   disc;
    aluno_node  aluno;
} lnode;
```

Then access them via:

```
List p;

p = some_function_returning_List();

if (is_disc(p)) {
    nome = p->disc.info.nome;
    p = p->disc.next;
}
else {
    num = p->aluno.info.numero;
    p = p->aluno.next;
}
```